# How to write an extension for all constant of struct?

Tags: ios, swift, struct

I have a Localization struct which helps to manage local keys.

```
struct Localization {

//Home
static let HomeHeader         =   "Home_Header"
static let HomeStatusActive   =   "Home_Status_Active"
static let HomeStatusDelayed  =   "Home_Status_Delayed"
}
```

Also, I have string extension which named as local to gives me the key from Localizable.strings file.

```
extension String {
    var local : String {
        return LocalizationManager.getLocalizedString(key: self)
    }
}
```

So when I need to localization key I use it like this;

```
titleLabel.text = Localization.HomeHeader.local
```

My question; Is there a way to perform an extension to use on every constant of struct without calling .local every time?

Basically, I want to call as below;

```
titleLabel.text = Localization.HomeHeader
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

To do minimal changes on what you have implemented till now. You could simply add local after string values.

```
struct Localization {

    //Home
    static let HomeHeader         =   "Home_Header".local
    static let HomeStatusActive   =   "Home_Status_Active".local
    static let HomeStatusDelayed  =   "Home_Status_Delayed".local
}

extension String {
    var local : String {
        return LocalizationManager.getLocalizedString(key: self)
    }
}
```

Then you will be able to use it like:

```
titleLabel.text = Localization.HomeHeader
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check below may be helpful to you

You can keep all your localised string in one place

```
struct ConstantsLocalized {
    static var key_loading: String {
        return "key_loading".localized()
    }
    static var key_placeholder_email: String {
        return "key_placeholder_email".localized()
    }
}
```

And you can access it with  `ConstantsLocalized.key_loading`

**EDIT**

I need to add one more advantage with this method, If you have in app localisation means user can change language from app it self then it is the best solution because you can get localise string every time

Hope it is helpful